# Formatting of a large and sparse matrix

Tags: formatting, matrices

For my Bachelorthesis, I need to make a large sparse matrix with long entries look reasonable. I am facing several issues:

1. The Matrix does not fit on the page
2. The \ddots look kind of ugly and are not aligned

This is what i have currently:
I set the size to footnotelength to try make it fit on the page. It still looks off and entries in the left corner are closer than elsewhere.

I am grateful for any help, I have been experimenting with different things (commented in code) but was unable to find a way to make it look reasonable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\footnotesize
%\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt} % default: 5pt
%\medmuskip = 1mu % default: 4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
\begin{bmatrix}
    L^2I_{n_0}+2\alpha\beta W_1^\mathsf{T} \Lambda_1 W_1 & - (\alpha + \beta)W_1^\mathsf{T}\Lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    - (\alpha + \beta)\Lambda_1W_1 & 2\Lambda_1 + 2 \alpha \beta W_2^\mathsf{T}\Lambda_2W_2 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\  
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 2\Lambda_{l-1} + 2 \alpha \beta W_l^\mathsf{T}\Lambda_lW_l & - (\alpha + \beta)W_l^\mathsf{T}\Lambda_l\\     
    0 & \cdots & 0 & - (\alpha + \beta)\Lambda_lW_l & 2\Lambda_l - W_{l+1}^\mathsf{T}W_{l+1}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, template for my bachelorthesis is smaller than a regular page. The result in my template can be seen in the picture.

[image]

Thanks in Advance for helping me!
Lukas

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I would use something like `\def\arraystretch{1.7}` for a better vertical alignment. To make the matrix fit the page you have to make the decision: reduce col sep `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.2pt}`, reduce fontsize or maybe split the matrix.

Comment: ... or split longer matrix entries into multiple lines using `multilined`, see [multiline equation inside a matrix that is a part of multiline equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491032/123129).

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I was trying to do was to reduce the overall space. Therefore,
the longer expressions are split into two lines and the left and right parts of the matrix are moved towards each other using negative spacing and separated only by diagonal dots. It should not be hard to add the rest of information if you feel they are missing.

Here's the solution:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\small
\begin{align}
  & M(L^2,\Lambda) = \nonumber \\
  & \hspace{1em}
  \mleft(
  \begin{array}{
      @{\hspace{-6pt}}
      *2{c}
      @{\hspace{-1.5em}}c@{\hspace{-1.5em}}
      *2{c}
      @{}
    }
    \begin{array}{c}
      L^2I_{n_0}\\{}+{} 2\alpha\beta W_1^\mathsf{T} \Lambda_1 W_1
    \end{array}
        & - (\alpha + \beta)W_1^\mathsf{T}\Lambda_1
        &&& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{\scalebox{3}{0}}}}
    \\[12pt]
    -(\alpha + \beta)\Lambda_1W_1
        & 2\Lambda_1 + 2 \alpha \beta W_2^\mathsf{T}\Lambda_2W_2
        &&&
    \\
    && \ddots &&
    \\
    &&& \begin{array}{c}
          2\Lambda_{l-1}\\{}+{} 2\alpha\beta W_l^\mathsf{T}\Lambda_lW_l
        \end{array}
        & - (\alpha + \beta)W_l^\mathsf{T}\Lambda_l
    \\[12pt]
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{\smash{\raisebox{-2ex}{\scalebox{3}{0}}}}
        &&& -(\alpha + \beta)\Lambda_lW_l
        & \begin{array}{c}
            2\Lambda_l\\{}-{} W_{l+1}^\mathsf{T}W_{l+1}
          \end{array}
  \end{array}
  \mright).
\end{align}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps!